# Find Numbers after a specific text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would recieve text like below
`CRM NO: 23542536 crmno:@ 3542536 crmno:_ 3542536...       crm no 43653768754`
my desired output will be:
23542536
3542536
3542536
43653768754
I want to write a regex to extract only the number after the string 'CRM NO'.

Also the CRM NO will come in variations like CRM NO or crmno or crm no

I have tried the regex `((?<=CRM NO)\D+\d+)` but not compatible with all the entries

Comment: If in your text there no strings different from CRM NO or crmno or crm no, so you only need to capture numeric values.

Comment: if it is the case then only search for digits: [https://regex101.com/r/SqY8P5/1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group with a case insensitive match and then match the leading part with an optional space

```
(?i)\bCRM ?NO\D+(\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fHWLEC/1)